# NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass... returns nil although its deprecated predecessor function worked

Tags: swift, deprecation-warning, nskeyedunarchiver

I have old code that uses `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData` to unarchive data.

```
let unarchivedData = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(archivedData)
```

unarchivedData then holds a `NSDictionary` that contains Strings, Ints, Dictionaries and NSData stuff.

As this function is deprecated I now use this function

```
let unarchivedData = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSDictionary.self, from: archivedData)
```

but unarchivedData now contains nil.

I have no idea why this new function does not work any more.
What could be the reason for this? Also using try/catch shows no hint in the error variable.

Comment: If it contains *Strings, Ints, Dictionaries and NSData stuff* you have to specify all classes and use `unarchivedObject(ofClasses…`. And ignoring the error with `try?` is not a good idea.

Comment: You're right! After I added all the classes now it it returns a working NSDictionary. Thanks!